# Exclude persistence.xml file from transitive Maven dependency

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am having a Maven project that randomly pulls one of the persistence.xml files from the transitive Maven dependencies. How can I configure the dependency to exclude its persistence.xml file?

For clarity, I'll elaborate this issue further:

I have a Maven project A. The pom file of A has a dependency B which in turn has dependencies C and D (A, B, C, and D are related projects) along with other dependencies. Projects C and D each have different persistence.xml files. So, when I build the project A *after* building projects B, C, and D, a persistence.xml file is randomly picked up from either C or D, and packaged with project A. I want to ensure that only the persistence.xml file from project C gets packaged in project A. How do I do this?

I can add more information if required.

Comment: If the dependency includes a persistence.xml which usually is a bad idea you can not exclude that file on a dependency level. The question is: Why is the `persistence.xml` file in the other projects? Furthermore it sounds like those projects are highly coupled. That sounds to me like a candidate for a multi module build (may be different thing). If you want to be sure to have the persistence.xml file from a particular dependency that means the persistence.xml file should be located in the project where you need it and not in dependant projects. (location in src/main/resources)...

Comment: Yes, it worked for me when I added the persistence.xml file in the project A. Can you write your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dependency includes a `persistence.xml` which usually is a bad idea you can not exclude that file on a dependency level.

The question is: Why is the `persistence.xml` file in the other projects?

Furthermore it sounds like those projects are highly coupled. That sounds to me like a candidate for a multi module build (may be different thing).

If you want to be sure to have the `persistence.xml` file from a particular dependency that means the `persistence.xml` file should be located in the project where you need it and not in dependant projects. (location in `src/main/resources`).